# Return value NaN from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

Here is my function, this works:

```
 my.SetTablepagerIndex = function() {
    var blah = $("#currentPage").text();
    var test = blah.indexOf("o");
    var pagerIndex = $.trim(blah.substring(4, test));
    return pagerIndex;
}
```

then, i'm assigning that to a var.  why doesnt this work?  I just get a 'NaN'

```
var index = Util.SetTablepagerIndex();
```

I don't want to declare a global variable, so if what i'm doing is a bad thing what's a better way to pass this value?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would produce `NaN`. Please post the actual code causing this issue.

Comment: You are correct, there isn't anything that would cause a NaN.  My functions are being called out of order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual issue is that my functions are being called out of order.  setTablepagerIndex is being called before the table for the pager has been created...

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the index is being interpreted as a string rather than an interger. Where are you getting `NaN`? For `index`?

You can try explicitly returning an integer, and you might want to test your transient variables (`blah`, `test`) to ensure that they exist:

```
my.SetTablepagerIndex = function() {
    var pagerIndex = -1;
    var blah = $("#currentPage").text();
    if (!blah) {
         return pagerIndex;
    }
    var test = blah.indexOf("o");
    if (!test) {
         return pagerIndex;
    }
    var trimmedString = $.trim(blah.substring(4, test));
    if (!trimmedString) {
         return pagerIndex;
    }

    //convert potential string into an integer
    return +trimmedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a string but I suspect you're using the return value like a number. If you tried to use the value like a number, and it's not a number, you'd get a NaN result.

Your problem is most likely that the substring is a bit off. Try tweaking the substring numbers a bit. If you provide the expected input string, `$("#currentPage").text()`, I could provide some help there.